# What would be an alternative concise statement for "were among X, but were not among Y"

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, phrases, expressions

I have the following statement:

> that strongest items were among the features associated with X, but
>   were not among those associated with the course content views.

However, I think that this statement is a bit hard-to-follow and it could become more concise. I am also not sure about its grammar.

My point is actually to stress out the second part starting with "**but not among...**". Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, you can drop some words. Have a look at [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)).

Comment: "The strongest items were not among the features associated with the course content views, as they were among X's features". OR "The strongest items were not among the features of the course content views, as they were among the features of X".

Comment: @mahmudkoya thanks! Does `as` suggest causality?

Comment: The first sentence seems to say that the strongest features were not reflected in the views of those taking the course..  The OP intends to "stress  out" the part of the first statement beginning with "but not among....".  That's confusing to me.

Comment: @renakre, you can use 'while' also: "The strongest items were not among the features of the course content, while they were among X's features".

Comment: None of the strongest features were associated with the course content views. Rather, they were found to be associated with X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By imposing the *criterion* on the *features* rather than the *items*, you can remove even more words to make it both more concise and more *readable*.

> ... that the strongest items were among the features associated with X,
>   but  <del>were</del>  not <del>among those associated</del> with the course content views.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds perfectly fine to me. Maybe the repetition and negation of among can be avoided: Synonymously, **absent** can be used. (edit: which leads to the concise antonym "present" instead of "among")

PS:

To omit repetition of "were" (ellipses, thanks to the comment) makes the sentence a tad harder to parse but shorter. There's a small trade-off and as it stands it tends to a formal tone.

"among the features associated" is a triple redundancy but repetition (edit: at various levels of detail) is a valid stylistic choice.